# Sliding div's and stacking them (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm in the middle of making my website and I got a little road bump. [This is how my code looks right now](https://jsfiddle.net/dpydwkap/), and what I want to do is have the "About" box right below the "Home" box and have the above box slide down with the description that comes when you click the "Home" box. How may I do that?

This is the code to my JS file.

```
$(document).ready(function (event) {
    var clicked=false;

    $(".one").on('click', function(){
        if(clicked)
        {
            clicked=false;
            $(".two").css({"top": -40}); //Slides upwards 40pixels       
        }
        else
        {
            clicked=true;
            $(".two").css({"top": 0});  //Slides righ under "one"      
        }
    });

    var clicked2=false;

    $(".three").on('click', function(){
        if(clicked2)
        {
            clicked2=false;
            $(".four").css({"top": -100}); //Slides upwards 40pixels       
        }
        else
        {
            clicked2=true;
            $(".four").css({"top": 0});  //Slides righ under "one"      
        }
    });
});
```

On a complete side note, how could I get the boxes to start from the top of the page and how could I make he box be a huge box rater than a tiny strip of color?

Comment: It could be done with [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

Comment: slideToggle() just like opens and closes it kinda thing, I want it to actually slide out rather than just open up

Comment: Actually, I think i'll just use slideToggle() haha, thanks for the idea!

Comment: Ok. You can see my answer otherwise

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
.container {
    overflow:hidden;
}
.one {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #FFC300;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.two {
    position: relative;
    top: -40px;
    background-color: yellow;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transition: top 1s;
    -moz-transition: top 1s;
    -o-transition: top 1s;
    transition: top 1s;
}
.three{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #E9A1B9;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.four {
    position: relative;
    top: -18px;
    background-color: #02C9C9;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transition: top 1s;
    -moz-transition: top 1s;
    -o-transition: top 1s;
    transition: top 1s;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/dpydwkap/1/)

Comment: Hey! Thanks, that solves one problem, however is there any way I could make the about bar fall right under the home bar rather than leave the gap the description of the Home bar would come to?

Also, do you know how to make the box a lot bigger? (Like quarter of the screen bigger) so I could center the text and change the font

Answer (score 0):

I would use a negative margins and toggle a simple `.open` class on the `.one` and `.three` divs :

```
$(".one, .three").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

CSS :

```
.one, .three {
    margin-bottom: -40px;
    -webkit-transition: margin-bottom 1s;
    -moz-transition: margin-bottom 1s;
    -o-transition: margin-bottom 1s;
    transition: margin-bottom 1s;
}
.open {margin-bottom: 0}
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/06cxutyu/)

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this a bit by using the jQuery toggle() function to do the work for you. (edit: you could also use slideToggle() for a different effect)

```
$(selector).toggle(speed,callback);
```

The optional speed parameter can take the following values: "slow", "fast", or milliseconds.

The optional callback parameter is a function to be executed after toggle() completes.

**html**

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="one">Main</div>
     <div class="two" style="display: none">Welcome to my page!</div>

     <div class="three">About</div>
     <div class="four" style="display: none">All about me</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.one {
    background-color: #FFC300;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.two {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.three{
    background-color: #E9A1B9;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.four {
    background-color: #02C9C9;
}
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function (event) {
  $(".one").on('click', function(){
      $(".two").toggle("slow");     
  });

  $(".three").on('click', function(){
      $(".four").toggle("slow");
  });
});
```

**DEMO:**

https://jsfiddle.net/qbuatjrm/4/